# I have a problem about serialize and deserialize struct use python

Tags: python, serialization

I want to create a class to serialize and deserialize  C style struct. The struct are nested and I am having trouble finding a way to serialize complex struct into dictionary myself. I want to code a class myself without using any helper function library. Is there any tutorial can help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify which version and give an example of our struct?

Comment: Sure for example a struct like {int32 number;int 32id;bool isalive{int32 number；bool isfull }inv;  } this is a protocal and every package i will send is following this protocal for example{"number":"321","id":1231,inv("number":1231),"isfull":false} I already create a function to serialize different  typr.The package being sent is stored in dic, I know dic has no order. How can I serialize this struct following the protocal order. For example number first ,then id then isalive... Many thanks!